# Fingerprint based authentication

Tags: android

I am developing an android app with fingerprint authentication only.

However , the users of the devices will not be the owners of the devices.

What I am creating is I want to store the user's fingerprint on registration, and then I want the user to be able to log in using only the registered fingerprint which will not be stored on the device settings?

Is this possible, if not , what is the alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Fingerprint of user will be stored in device by Android. Users will have to register their fingerprints on the device itself. What your app can do is ask a user for fingerprint and let android verify if this fingerprint belongs to an authorized user.